# How can I read rows in multiple csv files, store them, and then search through them WITHOUT using modules?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a csv file like this:

id  name   age   year,

1   John   30    2011

2   George 23    2018

The task is to search for a name and year for example and to print the age.

How can I do this?

I've tried storing them in a list, but the result was - I had a list of all items, which i couldn't search through.

Comment: Can you be more precise about the task? What are the search terms? Is it always a specific value for a year, or a specific value for a name? What is the output? Is it always a single value for age? What if your search terms have multiple matches?

Comment: All the items are unique. 
The task is to make the user input a name and a year.
The output should be the age (single value).

Comment: what delimiter are you using in your csv file?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific issues are you running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to store table data is as a list of dicts.

```
table = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": 30, "year": 2011},
    {"id": 2, "name": "George", "age": 23, "year": 2018}
]
```

I will leave it you to write the code that gets your csv into that form.

Then you can search the table relatively easily. Here's one way:

```
def get_age(name, year):
    for row in table:
        if row["name"] == name and row["year"] == year:
            return row["age"]

get_age("John", 2011)
>>> 30

get_age("John", 2012)
>>> None
```

I don't know where your "no modules" restriction comes from, but in the real world you would use `pandas` to do this. It's a ready-made library which provides these kind of data structures and operations.

Comment: The "no modules" restriction comes from my homework requirements. I feel like they just want us to suffer for no reason. Speaking of suffering, these are not all the names I have in the csv file, so I guess I first have to store them from the file in the table (which I'm not quite sure how to do). But your answer helped a lot, Thank You!

Comment: No problem. If it's just an exercise then it's quite a good one to challenge you in the basics of Python. Remember to upvote and mark this as the answer if it helped your problem.

Comment: I'm new here, so my upvote seems to have 0 value, but I marked it as the answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Store them as a dict, this way you can search the data by key and value.